# JS Object.create() in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I'm constructing two JS object in Dart. In JS, they are constructed with Object.create():

```javascript
var wavesurfer1 = Object.create(WaveSurfer);
var wavesurfer2 = Object.create(WaveSurfer);
```

This is what I think is Dart equivalent:

```dart
var wavesurfer1 = context['WaveSurfer'];
var wavesurfer1 = context['WaveSurfer'];
```

But, I found that the two objects in Dart appear to be the same. When I call a function in one object it gets triggered in both. This does not happen in the JS code. I suspect that Object.create() should not be written as context[''] in Dart. If this is true, I'm not able to find an example in dartlang.org or stackoverflow.com for how to correctly translate this expression to Dart. You can see the JS source code for WaveSurfer [here](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/blob/master/src/wavesurfer.js).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `context['WaveSurfer']` you get a *JsObject* corresponding to the Js *WaveSurfer* and not to a new object.

To do the Dart equivalent of your pasted JS code :

```dart
import 'dart:js';

var wavesurfer = context['WaveSurfer'];
var wavesurfer1 = context['Object'].callMethod('create', [waveSurfer]);
var wavesurfer2 = context['Object'].callMethod('create', [waveSurfer]);
```

See [Using JavaScript from Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/).

If you find the usage of *dart:js* to hard and verbose you can use *package:js* that provides a simplier API (but with a larger JS generated size) :

```dart
import 'package:js/js.dart';

var wavesurfer1 = context.Object.create(context.WaveSurfer);
var wavesurfer2 = context.Object.create(context.WaveSurfer);
```

Comment: Alexandre. I tried this before but I get this expection: `Exception: TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null`.

Comment: Sorry. I misread your code. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: Alexandre. I found the compiled JS code behaves differently. It appears to create one object from the two constructors. Is this a bug in dart2js?